# Background image is not correct on the mobile

Tags: css

My background image on the [mobile becomes very fuzzy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2QkZ.jpg).

But on [DevTools is Correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfeKE.png).

Is so weird, how to fix it?

```
.contact
  padding: 80px 30px
  color: #fff
  background: #151515 url('../src/assets/images/about.jpg') no-repeat fixed left bottom
  min-height: 100%
  background-size: cover
  position: relative
```

Comment: You can do debbug from your mobile. Connect your phone to your pc: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

Comment: _What_ mobile in particular? Running Safari 6 perhaps? See https://caniuse.com/#search=background-size, note #2 then.

Comment: Or the known issues, _“iOS Safari has buggy behavior with background-size: cover; + background-attachment: fixed;”_

Answer (score 0):

Without a code to test I think the issue comes from the `fixed` attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment

If you remove it, it should show the image fitting the viewport and cutting the part that can't display. Since the image is much bigger that the viewport, when you use fixed it will show you that part of the image that fits the current viewport.

So try:

```
background: #151515 url('../src/assets/images/about.jpg') no-repeat left bottom;
```

Comment: If you want to keep the fixed background on desktop you could use media queries

Answer (score 0):

Background image is not correct on the mobile. You css background-size mobile:

```
background-size: contain;
```